# Using XPath functions in Nustache

Tags: c#, xml, mustache, nustache

In Nustache (Mustache for C#) you can use an XML document as the data for rendering, and then you can use XPath expressions that return nodes in the templates, like `{{parent/child/node}}`

Is it possible to use XPath functions in the templates?

It'll be very useful to use something like `{{sum(ítems/price)}}`

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing something like this:

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Price");

    // Using HtmlAgilityPack Library
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

    doc.Load("FILE_PATH_TO_YOUR_XML_FILE");

    // Get the XPath Value
    string xPath_Price = "price";

    // Now get all of the prices

    foreach (HtmlNode price in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//price"))
    {
         DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

         dr["Price"] = price.SelectSingleNode(xPath_Price).InnerText;
         dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    // Now Serialize this data and store it as a string
    // Use Newtonsoft.Json Library
    string all_prices = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);

    // Now use this string and store it as a ViewBag Object to use in your View

    ViewBag.XPathPrices = all_prices;

    return View();

}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="PricesContainer">
    @ViewBag.XPathPrices
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I understand that this code will do the sum operating on the data for the particular case of sum. It's ok, but what we need is a generic solution for using the whole XPath function set

Comment: @Bill-Velasquez You can expand on this function and put in whatever XPath you want and then create another method for the ViewBag object.  Then you can just call it in your View.